# Which IDE do I use to develop a mono app in IronPython?

Tags: mono, ironpython, monodevelop

I'm investigating which platform to use for a cross platform GUI app that needs access to the serial port. Currently I'm thinking on using the mono runtime and monodevelop as the IDE. However, I already have a corpus of prototype code written python. Therefore, my idea was to write the mono app in IronPython as well, but as far as I can find on the net, monodevelop has no support for IronPython.

Therefore my question. Which IDE should I use, given that I want to develop the app on top of mono and use the IronPython language? Also, I don't want to invest into a windows license as I run OSX and Linux only.

Cheers,
Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people seem to use Eclipse with [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) extensions.

Answer (score 4):

See [voidspace review of IDEs for IronPython](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/tools-and-ides.shtml) This site also covers a lot of other info for IronPython.

Answer (score 3):

There was a beta release of [MonoDevelop 2.2](http://monodevelop.com/index.php?title=Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.2) with improved Python support.  See if that meets your needs.

Comment: Note this mainly for normal Python, I don't know how ipy support is.