# IronPython - DynamicWebServiceHelpers.dll in linux?

Tags: python, linux, mono, ironpython

The examples shown in the IronPython sample scripts show the ability to use DynamicWebServiceHelpers.dll as so:

```
 import clr
 clr.AddReference('DynamicWebServiceHelpers.dll')
 import DynamicWebServiceHelpers
```

This does not however work...

```
 IOError: Could not add reference to assembly DynamicWebServiceHelpers
```

So I tried to find and build DynamicWebServiceHelpers myself - but could find little to no help on google; long story short I couldn't get the vsproj file to build properly.

I've tried this in IronPython 2.6, 2.0, Iron Python Community Edition 2 and none of them work on linux.  In fact the file `DynamicWebServiceHelpers.dll` isn't even present on Linux installs.

How in the world do you find/use the DynamicWebServiceHelpers module on linux with IronPython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamicWebServiceHelpers is one of the sample projects for IronPython.  You are correct in that you would have to build it from source.  In looking at the source code, all of the referenced C# assemblies/namespaces should have Mono support.

Make sure you have the most recent version of Mono installed along with Ironpython 2.7.

This [forum](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td1500464)  talks about converting project files and or using MonoDevelop.
See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404355/which-ide-do-i-use-to-develop-a-mono-app-in-ironpython) 
And check out [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

I would recommend trying again with MonoDevelop 2.4, Ironpython 2.7 and Mono 2.10.xx and posting a new question with any specific issues you have in building DynamicWebServiceHelpers.dll

Comment: Thanks for the info - that shines some light on the problem, I'll try to see where I can get based on your recommendations